# time format in VB6 not compare

Tags: vba, vb6

I have this condition in VB6 :

```
If ((Time >= #12:20:00 PM# And Time <= #3:00:00 PM# And boolTarde = False)
```

I want to change this fixed values  (`#12:20:00 PM#` and  `#3:00:00 PM#`) by variables. 
I have loaded the values `"12:20:00"` and   `"03:00:00"` in the string variables `InitAmanha` and `FimAmanha` , hence I have written a new condition:

```
 If ((Time >= InitAmanha And Time <= FimAmanha And boolTarde = False)
   end if
```

However, this doesn't compare anything. Is it necessary to concatenate the `'PM#'`?

Comment: The `#` signs delimit Date type literals.  Why would you be trying to substitute String variables if you have Date values to compare?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `TimeValue` function natively available in VBA. 
For example:

```
Dim myStrDate1 As String: myStrDate1 = "4:25:32" 
Dim myDate1 As Date: myDate1 = TimeValue(myStrDate1)
'--> myDate1 will be interpreted as 4.25 in the morning
```

Please note that you can specify the `AM` / `PM` if you want:

```
Dim myStrDate1 As String: myStrDate1 = "4:25:32 PM" 
Dim myDate1 As Date: myDate1 = TimeValue(myStrDate1)
'--> myDate1 will be interpreted as 4.25 in the afternoon
```

However, if you do *not* specify it, the time will always be interpreted as AM (that means 4:25:32 will always be 4:25:32 AM).

In your specific case:

```
If ((Time >= TimeValue(InitAmanha) And Time <= TimeValue(FimAmanha) And boolTarde = False)
   End If
```